# Knapsack when weight and values are positive?

Tags: algorithm

What is the most accurated algorithm to Knapsack when weight and values are positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what language your using but Wikipedia has a great page on information and algorithms to solve it.  If you want more sample code to understand how to do it, check this site out: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Unbounded/Python_dynamic_programming  (this is all in python but there's more languages).

Basically it depends on what your doing but the most common way to solve this is dynamic programming.